# Hosting for CIVICRM -

Tags: hosting-providers

Our live CIVICRM environment is CiviCRM 5.67.1, Joomla 4.4.2, PHP 8.1, hosted on Siteground. Looking to move from Siteground dedicated hosting - too many issues and super slow.  Looking for advice from the community as to the best performing hosting service for Joomla and CIVICRM

Comment: I'd recommend to use a **Linux server with Plesk Control Panel.** I use Joomla since the first days and can confirm, that it performs best on Linux servers (php-fpm!), nginx/Apache mixed environment, with an easy-to-use Plesk Server Control Panel.

Take a hoster near you which offers this combination.

Answer (score 2):

I have had various problems with shared hosting recently, so your question resonates with me. I'm currently planning on moving an install to Civihosting.com, after mailing problems. I've used them before and I know others recommend them. One thing for sure, not all shared hosting sites can run CiviCRM.

Answer (score 1):

Here's where you can find official list of CiviCRM partner/experts:

https://civicrm.org/civicrm/experts

If you put in "hosting" as the service and "joomla" as the CMS it looks like there are 7 options.